# What aspects of signed left shift are undefined with GCC?

Tags: c, gcc, bit-shift

Basically I am asking for a translation of:

> GCC does not use the latitude given in C99 only to treat certain aspects of signed `<<' as undefined, but this is subject to change.

([GCC 4.8.1 manual, paragraph 4.5](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.8.1/gcc/Integers-implementation.html#Integers-implementation))

What 'latitude' is given? Which certain aspects?

Comment: Great question! That sentence should gain the first prize for fogginess! I'm not a native English speaker, so I cannot be 100% sure, but my English skills are quite advanced and I'm still puzzled by that word "only". I can't decide to what other terms it refers.  *Only* C99 uses latitude? *Only* certain aspects are treated with latitude. GCC does not use latitude *only* for signed `<<`? This latter seems the best interpretation, but then what "certain aspects": possible UBs causes are just a couple, it would have been much simpler to say what GCC currently does and warn about future changes!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Other answers have already pointed out which aspects of `<<` are undefined behavior. My guess is that you want a "translation" of the gcc into common language.

If a behavior is undefined by the C standard, compiler implementors can take the "latitude" to do anything that suits them if such a case occurs. In particular, they don't have to implement a diagnostic or detection of that case, and may pretend that it never happens. It is the responsability of the programmer to write his program such that its behavior is always defined.

In the case of left shift, this means that a compiler would not have to check for overflow and can pretend that a loop like

```
for (int i = 1; i > 0; i <<= a) {
 .... change a in some complicated way ...
}
```

would never terminate.

The sentence that you are citing indicates that they don't do such a thing, yet, but that future versions of gcc might do so.

Answer (score 3):

C99 §6.5.7/3-4 lists two specific undefined behaviors regarding the left shift operator (`<<`):

> 3) [...] If the value of the right operand is negative or is greater than or equal to the width of the promoted left operand, the behavior is undefined.
>
> 4) The result of `E1 << E2` is [...]. If `E1` has a signed type and nonnegative value, and `E1` × 2<sup>`E2`</sup> is representable in the result type, then that is the resulting value; otherwise, the behavior is undefined.

How exactly GCC behaves in these circumstances, I can't say.  It's perfectly welcome to give defined behavior in these situations; however, such code will still be undefined when compiled with other compilers.

My *guess* is that GCC treats signed left shifting identically to unsigned left shifting—that is, if computes `x << y` as `(signed)((unsigned)x << y)` by doing the bit shifts (potentially discarding any upper bits), and then reinterpreting the result as a signed quantity.  This has the implication that the most-significant value bit of a signed integer gets shifted into the sign bit; that seems a little strange from an arithmetic perspective but makes perfect sense from a bitwise perspective.

Answer (score 3):

The informations on the left shift operator in C99 draft standard (ISO/IEC9899:TC3, aka WG14/N1256) are rather scant.

Section 6.5.7 (bitwise shift operators) has already been cited by Alter Mann.

Annex J, section J.2 (Undefined behavior) says the following:

> The behavior is undefined in the following circumstances:
>   [...]
>
> — An expression is shifted by a negative number or by an amount greater than or equal
>   to the width of the promoted expression (6.5.7).
>
> — An expression having signed promoted type is left-shifted and either the value of the
>   expression is negative or the result of shifting would be not be representable in the
>   promoted type (6.5.7).

I don't think it is allowed for a conforming implementation to make some mandatory undefined behavior defined. If I'm not mistaken an implementation is allowed to define **unspecified behavior** (but it is not required to) and is required to specify **implementation defined behavior**, but undefined behavior cannot be *specified*. This doesn't mean that an implementation cannot choose a *sane meaningful behavior*, but it cannot let the user rely on that (it cannot "specify it").

I admit I'm not completely sure of that. Hope this helps.

**Edit:** Upon further reflection I think a conforming implementation *can specify* a behavior for what the standard deems **undefined behavior**, but the resulting program cannot be called conforming (see section 3.4.3).

Comment: For an example of undefined behavior that was always intended to be (and routinely is) defined by compilers, an unknown `%` sequence in a `printf()` format string is undefined behavior.

Comment: So if an implementation specifies a defined behavior, where it is required to specify undefined behavior, that implementation is exhibiting undefined behavior? Kafkaesque...

Answer (score 0):

The [current documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Integers-implementation.html#Integers-implementation) says:

> - The results of some bitwise operations on signed integers (C90 6.3, C99 and C11 6.5).
>
>   [...]
>
>   As an extension to the C language, GCC does not use the latitude given in C99 and C11 only to treat certain aspects of signed `<<` as undefined. However, `-fsanitize=shift` (and `-fsanitize=undefined`) will diagnose such cases. They are also diagnosed where constant expressions are required.

i.e. it is not going to change any more. The rather vague wording means that the behaviour that was **explicitly mentioned** as undefined in C99, C11, which is the

> [...] If E1 has a signed type and nonnegative value, and E1 x 2<sup>E2</sup> is representable in the result type, then that is the resulting value; otherwise, the behavior is undefined.

Because that is what **changed from C89 to C99**, i.e. is not present in C89, but **only** C99 and C11. So GCC says that a) integers will have 2's complement representation, and b) the bitshift operator **if** shifted left by **less than the width of the left operand**, the result is the 2's complement representation shifted left, i.e. as if the number was first cast to unsigned of the same width, then the bit shift performed on that unsigned value and finally converted to the 2's complement signed number having the same presentation.

However shifting by the width of the promoted left operand or **more** was explicitly undefined in C89 too, so it does not fall under the "explicit undefined behaviour mentioned in C99, C11".